# Sparse matrix of zeros

Tags: python

I have this code :

```
M=np.zeros((N,N),dtype=complex)
M=sparse.bsr_matrix(M)
M[0][0]=complex(1,1)
print(M)
```

I am trying to create an NxN sparse matrix of zeros that I can then add numbers into. Could someone please tell me why it is giving me an error? Thanks!

Comment: Please, post the error, be more specific.

Comment: I believe sparse matrices have a unique representation that do not allow you to directly set the values. I'm not certain but maybe try setting the values you want and then converting it to a sparse matrix.

Comment: @hoffee: Most of them can be changed incrementally (although you may not want to); [`sparse.lil_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.lil_matrix) is useful if you have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`bsr_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.bsr_matrix.html) represents a block sparse matrix, you can't change its elements by index. Perhaps you were looking for something like [`csr_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix)? With that, paying attention to the warning it produces, you can do what you are trying to do:

```
In [192]: M = sparse.csr_matrix((N, N), dtype=np.complex)

In [193]: M[0, 0] = np.complex(1, 1)
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py:742: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)

In [194]: print(M)
  (0, 0)        (1+1j)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
M = np.zeros((N,N),dtype=complex)
M[0][0] = complex(1,1)
M = sparse.bsr_matrix(M)

print(M)

#   (0, 0)  (1+1j)
```

You cannot set the values of a sparse matrix directly, but you can set the values of a numpy array and then convert it to a sparse matrix.

Comment: This would be wasteful for any scale where sparse matrices are helpful.